# Basic Dictionay (key maps the value)

Tags: python, dictionary

[image]
What is the back-end of this situation, where two same keys have different values but the output is little strange? What's going on?

Comment: python dict can't have two records with the same key

Comment: on a side note please do take a read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), following it is a benefit for all of us. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are indexed by Keys. If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten. It is an error to extract a value using a non-existent key.

Read more about dictionaries in https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries before using them

Answer (score 0):

an one-line excerpt from python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value
>   associated with that key is forgotten.

I guess it's easier for you to understand it with some codes here.

```
d = {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'a':'C'}
d['a'] 

# output
'C'

print(d)
# output 
{'b':'B', 'a':'C'}
```

it's not very hard to see that python has deleted the old key value pair for `a` here and the dictionary itself has only 2 items in it. this is basically what python meant by **forgotten**.